# not viewing specific saved conversation Javascript

Tags: exchangewebservices, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Basically my application can read saved conversation via Skype For Business. But Skype for business can not read saved conversations via my application.

I use JavaScript while I am developing my application.

Below more details;

I am trying to make a save to conversation history folder and see it properly in the native Skype for Business client.

Here is my SOAP request:

```http
POST /EWS/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: <username>:<password>@<domain>
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
      <m:SavedItemFolderId>
        <t:FolderId Id="AAMkADI2ZWUxY2Y4LTM4MjQtNGRiMC04NGU5LWNjMTkwMmI2ZGZhYwAuAAAAAAARYud90uTpQaW383uiLjbQAQBu8bl+jmTVT6UWWk0qHuXQAAAA2qSWAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAABYAAABu8bl+jmTVT6UWWk0qHuXQAAAA2q+x" />
      </m:SavedItemFolderId>
      <m:Items>
        <t:Message>
          <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note.Microsoft.Conversation</t:ItemClass>
          <t:Subject>Conversation with John Doe</t:Subject>
          <t:Body BodyType="HTML">
            <![CDATA[<head
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:history="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems"
            xmlns:rtc="urn:microsoft-rtc-xslt-functions"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><style type="text/css">
            <!-- @charset "utf-8"; body { margin-left: 11px; margin-top: 11px; margin-right: 11px; margin-bottom: 11px; } p { margin:0; padding:0; } .header { font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-family: "Segoe UI"; } .callDuration { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; } .notes_bkg { background-color: #e4eefc; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #b5c4df; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 8px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 20px; } .notes_title { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #15429d; text-decoration: none; } .note_message { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #15429d; text-decoration: none;} .list_name { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; line-height: 18px; } .list_title_company { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: uppercase; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; } .list_label { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 25px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none; } .links { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #0000FF; text-decoration: underline; } .line { border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: #b5c4df; height: 1px; background-color: #b5c4df; } .footer_line { padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; } .footer { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none; padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 8px; } .header_box { padding-top: 11px; padding-bottom: 11px; } .contacts_box { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 80px; } .list_value { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 25px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; } .im_sender { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; } .message_timestamp { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; } .messageInfo { margin-left:8px; } .notification { font-family: "Segoe UI"; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; line-height: 18px; font-weight: normal; font-variant: normal; text-transform: none; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; } -->
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:history="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems"
            xmlns:rtc="urn:microsoft-rtc-xslt-functions">
            <span>My Name</span>
            <span>05:28 PM:</span>
            <div>
              <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)"
                <style>
                  <!-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face {font-family:"Cambria Math"; panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;} @font-face {font-family:"Segoe UI"; panose-1:2 11 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal {margin-top:0cm; margin-right:0cm; margin-bottom:8.0pt; margin-left:0cm; line-height:107%; font-size:11.0pt; font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} .MsoChpDefault {font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;} .MsoPapDefault {margin-bottom:8.0pt; line-height:107%;} /* Page Definitions */ @page WordSection1 {size:612.0pt 792.0pt; margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;} div.WordSection1 {page:WordSection1;} -->
                </style>
                <div>
                  <p style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal;text-autospace:none">
                    <span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">test</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </body></html>]]>
        </t:Body>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="ConversationXml.{CA2F170A-A22B-4f0a-B899-93439DEC3FBC}" PropertyType="String" />
          <t:Value>&lt;conversations
            xmlns=&quot;http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems&quot; minSupportedClientVersion=&quot;3.0.0.0&quot;&gt;&lt;conversationXml&gt;&lt;/conversationXml&gt;&lt;/conversations&gt;
          </t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="Direction.{2DA4DF04-920D-4b0b-A1D7-5FC9D21857FE}" PropertyType="Integer" />
          <t:Value>1</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="Modalities.{0885EA21-B7A5-4050-BFDB-AD46DE1D6A87}" PropertyType="Integer" />
          <t:Value>1</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="IsCustomSubject.{703DC3CB-8F24-4e3f-932F-206233656759}" PropertyType="Integer" />
          <t:Value>0</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="DisplayDirection.{4255C773-497E-4b5e-9205-F360CAF3316A}" PropertyType="String" />
          <t:Value>Incoming</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="RemoteParty.{664AD731-19D0-4344-93FD-682FE0440D95}" PropertyType="String" />
          <t:Value>john.doe@domain</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="HistoryInfo.{553F3F08-FC28-41db-859E-63457407F806}" PropertyType="String" />
          <t:Value>john.doe@domain</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ExtendedProperty>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="3591" PropertyType="Integer" />
          <t:Value>1</t:Value>
        </t:ExtendedProperty>
        <t:ToRecipients>
          <t:Mailbox>
            <t:EmailAddress>john.doe@domain</t:EmailAddress>
          </t:Mailbox>
          <t:Mailbox>
            <t:EmailAddress>my.account@domain</t:EmailAddress>
          </t:Mailbox>
        </t:ToRecipients>
        <t:From>
          <t:Mailbox>
            <t:Name>My Name</t:Name>
            <t:EmailAddress>my.account@domain</t:EmailAddress>
          </t:Mailbox>
        </t:From>
      </t:Message>
    </m:Items>
  </m:CreateItem>
</soap:Body>undefined</soap:Envelope>
```

I use dummy data in the request above. Folder Id inside the tag `<SavedItemFolderId>` is Id of Conversion History folder. The request has also a quite big HTML content with styles.

I can save the item into Conversation History folder and see it in my Outlook client.

Although I can see it as a Conversation History item in native Skype for Business Windows client, I cannot see the conversation content (messages) when I double click it.

I think I am doing configuration or HTML content in wrong way.

Has anyone ever tried to save conversation history and see it in native client? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: do you have any comment for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved tihs problem.

the real problem is, you are genetaring conversationXml but you do not put your messages body inside of this conversationXML. So if you give the parameter as below, you will solve the problem.

you will see +body+ (body formatted as HTML)

by the way you should give spesifically wihch format you are putting the body (text/HTML, text/RTF)

```
let cnvXML ='<conversations xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems\" minSupportedClientVersion=\"3.0.0.0\"><conversationXml><imReceived xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2008/10/sip/convItems\" ts=\"2017-11-14T07:18:47Z\" from=\"sip:tan.tastan@gbsolutions.work\" displayName=\"Tan Tastan\" firstMessage=\"true\" type=\"text/html\"><messageInfo type=\"text/html\" msgid=\"\" sequenceid=\"0\">'+body+'</messageInfo></imReceived></conversationXml></conversations>';
```

Then you must change these two parameters as below;

...SetExtendedProperty(RemoteParty, "sip:participantsName@yourDomain.com");
...SetExtendedProperty(HistoryInfo, "sip:participantsName@yourDomain.com");

After that, you will realize another problem which is in Native Skype's History tab, you will see message preview is not shown. So if you add the parameter as below, you will solve second problem.

...SetExtendedProperty(PreviewMessage, messagePreview);

I hope I explained the solution clearly.